# How to run independent requirements.txt file in apache airflow DAG

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have multiple aiflow dags running on composer environment. For now I haven't get a chance to install any extra python packages apart from the packages given by airflow. But now I want to install beautifulsoup and other packager for two different DAGs. How can I do that?

**1st approach:**

```
def a():
   print("Response")
   return True

response = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
    task_id = "response",
    requirements=["lxml==4.9.1","beautifulsoup4==4.11.1"],
    python_callable = a,
    dag=dag,
    provide_context=True
)
```

Its installing the packages, but not executing the code. It's just skipping job. I want to know what's happing backend and How would I can execute the code.

**2nd Approach:**

```
virtual_classic = BashOperator(
    task_id="virtual_classic",
    bash_command="bash /home/airflow/gcs/dags/test_req/requirements.txt",
    dag=dag
)
```

Here I was trying to install all the packages from requirements file and then trying to run required necessary code. But here I'm not sure how to install this file through airflow operators? Appreciate your valuable suggestions here.

**3rd Approach:**

```
gcloud composer environments update ENVIRONMENT_NAME \
--location LOCATION \
 --update-pypi-packages-from-file gs://composer_bucket/requirements.txt
```

**Error:**

*gcloud crashed (TypeError): cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object*

Please let me know the best way to install requirement.txt files for independent dags out of three.

Comment: It's exactly for that that I'm fighting against Composer: Developers mix Orchestration (#1 job of Airflow) and business processing (your current issue). You shouldn't run business processing directly in Composer but invoke (orchestrate calls) to external processing solution: Cloud Run, Cloud Functions, or even the KubernetesPodOperator as proposed by Mazlum, but NEVER directly in the orchestrator/DAG

Answer (score 1):

By default with `Airflow` and `Cloud Composer`, the `pypi` packages are installed in the machines for all the DAGs globally.

If you want having versions and packages per DAG or task, you can use
the [KubernetesPodOperator](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/use-kubernetes-pod-operator)

This operator allows to use a custom `Docker` image.
In this image, you can install and isolate all the needed packages for this task and `Python` program.

The `Docker` image used in the operator needs to be published in `Container registry` in the same project (I am not sure if it's possible with `Artifact Registry`).

Example of this operator in the documentation :

```py
kubernetes_min_pod = KubernetesPodOperator(
        # The ID specified for the task.
        task_id="pod-ex-minimum",
        # Name of task you want to run, used to generate Pod ID.
        name="pod-ex-minimum",
        # Entrypoint of the container, if not specified the Docker container's
        # entrypoint is used. The cmds parameter is templated.
        cmds=["echo"],
        # The namespace to run within Kubernetes, default namespace is
        # `default`. In Composer 1 there is the potential for
        # the resource starvation of Airflow workers and scheduler
        # within the Cloud Composer environment,
        # the recommended solution is to increase the amount of nodes in order
        # to satisfy the computing requirements. Alternatively, launching pods
        # into a custom namespace will stop fighting over resources,
        # and using Composer 2 will mean the environment will autoscale.
        namespace="default",
        # Docker image specified. Defaults to hub.docker.com, but any fully
        # qualified URLs will point to a custom repository. Supports private
        # gcr.io images if the Composer Environment is under the same
        # project-id as the gcr.io images and the service account that Composer
        # uses has permission to access the Google Container Registry
        # (the default service account has permission)
        image="gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/ubuntu_18_0_4",
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have different options to run your dags in isolated environments:

1. Run the tasks in separate python virtual environments: similar to your first approach, but installing the requirements on each run is not a good idea, instead you can create the environments manually (or using a CI/CD), and install all the packages you need for the two dags, then you can use the bash operator and call the command `/path/to/<venv1 or venv2>/bin/python some_script.py`
2. Run them as docker containers on the VM using [DockerOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker/index.html#airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker.DockerOperator): in this case the tasks will be executed in isolated containers, you just need to create the 2 docker images with the needed packages for each dag, push them to a docker registry (ex Google Docker Registry), then provide the tag of the appropriate image for each dag.
3. Run them as Kubernetes pods using [KubernetesPodOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/operators.html#kubernetespodoperator): in this case the tasks will be executed outside the cloud composer cluster (which is a group of pods running on GKE cluster), and they will be running as separate pods. You need to create the images and push them to a docker registry as explained  in the second option, then configure Airflow to access your GKE cluster ([here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/use-gke-operator) is the official documentation)